# German localisation of biblatex-chem-angew

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I'm using `biblatex-chem-angew` with a MikTeX system like this:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
```

I want to use a German localisation, because

> [1] H. G. O. Becker, R. Beckert, Organikum, Wiley-VCH, Weinheim, 23rd
>   ed.,
>   2009.

is not good in a German text ("23. Auflage" would be better). Is this possible?

Furthermore, how can I cite like this:

Import thesis. [1-3] or another.[1,3]?

Is this already included?

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example of your input? `biblatex` should automatically pick up `babel` use and localise strings, for example. I'm also not sure what you mean about `Import thesis.[1-3] or another.[1,3]`: what did you try?

Comment: @JosephWright Maybe he is looking for `comp`/compact?

Comment: @Johannes_B `chem-angew` is derived from `numeric-comp`, so compression is automatically included

Comment: @JosephWright Oh, ok.

Comment: Ok, I found the mistake, I used "\usepackage{ngerman}". Replacing with "\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}" yieled in the desired result:

[1] H. G. O. Becker, R. Beckert, Organikum, Wiley-VCH, Weinheim, 23. Aufl.,
2009.

I wanted to ask, if there is a makro, which can various citation convert into one bracket.

Something, which needs three sources.\cite{Cit1}\cite{Cit2}\cite{Cit3} becomes
Something, which needs three sources.[1-3]

and

Something, which needs three sources.\cite{Cit1}\cite{Cit3}\cite{Cit10} becomes
Something, which needs three sources.[1,3,10]

Comment: OK, I got it, numeric-comp was a good point, I found the solution: \cite{Cit1,Cit2,Cit3} Really thanks for your rapid answers :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it stems from an attempt to load a package option as the package itself.

Comment: @Jubobs Closing is right in my opinion, too. But the reason you mention is wrong: There _is_ a package `ngerman` – this is considered obsolete, though.

Comment: @Speravir I didn't know that. My mistake.